# Difficulty using usaddress.parse on a datset. (In python)

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm trying parse lines of address data from a csv. My algorithm is supposed to read through the lines, and take out all unique addresses, leaving the duplicates, and post them to a new csv. My error is that it simply posts the first line or "address" into the csv. Any tips?

Comment: Could you add your code? Without that it is very hard to debug. Furthermore you could add an error message so people know what is going on. Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to post some more details to go on, and the csv part may not be part of the problem. Do you get the right values if you just print them out? Get that working, and then add the "write to a csv" part. Maybe even post a very short "here's some original data with duplicates, and here's what the output file should look like" sample data.

Comment: Here's a simple check for your algorithm: if these were addresses, what should the result be:  `A A B C C D A B B A`